# How to use custom font in Apache FOP in Java

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm using FOP to create PDF programatically.

But I cannot change the default font... I want to use a specific font.
So I downloaded the ttf file for that font but I cannot make that the text appears in that font.

This is my Java class which loads the conf file and which use the xsl file.

```
public File createPDFFile(ByteArrayOutputStream xmlSource) throws IOException, SAXException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("" + System.currentTimeMillis(), EXTENSION);
        URL url = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/UserId.xsl").getFile()).toURI().toURL();
        // creation of transform source
        StreamSource transformSource = new StreamSource(url.openStream());
        // create an instance of fop factory
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/conf.xconf").getFile()));
        // a user agent is needed for transformation
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
        // to store output
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfoutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlSource.toByteArray()));
        Transformer xslfoTransformer;
        try {
            TransformerFactory transfact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            xslfoTransformer = transfact.newTransformer(transformSource);
            // Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop;
            try {
                fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, pdfoutStream);
                // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO)
                // must be piped through to FOP
                Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                try {
                    // everything will happen here..
                    xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res);

                    // if you want to save PDF file use the following code
                    OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
                    out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);
                    FileOutputStream str = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    str.write(pdfoutStream.toByteArray());
                    str.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (TransformerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (FOPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Then in my config:

```
....
<fonts>
           <font embed-url="ChaletNewYorkNineteenEighty.ttf">
              <font-triplet name="Chalet" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
              <font-triplet name="Chalet" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
            </font>
....
```

And in my XLS:

```
<fo:block border="solid 0.1mm black" font-family="Chalet" font-size="8pt" font-weight="normal">
```

But in the output is always with the standar font and in the console I get the following:

```
WARN  org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - Font "Chalet,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `embed-url` is incorrect.

> Relative URLs are resolved relative to the font-base property (or base) if available
>   https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#register

Comment: Did you clear your font cache, as described further down:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#font-cache

Another idea is to reference the directory where your font is located:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#bulk

Comment: Is this valid if I'm using Maven to download fop dependency? I cannot find any .fop folder

Comment: I don't see a reason why the maven dependency should behave differently. There is either a ".fop" directory in user home or a "fop-fonts.cache" file in the temp directory.

Answer (score 0):

`Chalet` font not declared with font style `style="normal"` and font weight `weight="700"` in the conf.xconf file. but you try to use `Chalet` font with `font-weight="700"` and `style="normal"` in the your XLS template. hence, get this error

> WARN  org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent - Font "Chalet,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700"

config the `Chalet` font with `style="normal"` and `weight="700"`

```
<fonts>
    <font embed-url="ChaletNewYorkNineteenEighty.ttf">
        <font-triplet name="Chalet" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        <font-triplet name="Chalet" style="normal" weight="700"/>
        <font-triplet name="Chalet" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    </font>
    .........
</fonts>
```